# iOS Document Imaging APIs

Tags: ios, document, imaging

The number of iOS applications that scan, crop, edge detect, and OCR documents has proliferated. Also I am aware of the number of programming APIs that have these features for desktop applications, like Nuance OmniPage, AtlasSoft, and GDPicture.

Is there a popular API or cloud service that an iOS developer should consider using when attempting to build such an app?  Or is this the wrong way to ask this question?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing... did you find anything useful? I don't need OCR, but I would like to be able to do scanning, edge detection, cropping and image adjustment "offline" (i.e. without requiring a server).

Comment: @jksoegaard have you found any library. i am also looking for same

Comment: @Hasham Found multiple commercial cloud APIs for this. However, haven't found any free libraries.

Comment: OpenCV will be my choice for free.

Comment: @jksoegaard You might check out [Dynamsoft Camera SDK for iOS](https://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/mobile-imaging-sdk.aspx).

Comment: @Rachel That SDK is not only commercial, but also requires Windows on the server. It’s not going to work for me.

Comment: @jksoegaard The iOS SDK doesn't require a Windows server. It is a commercial option though. I'm sorry that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Commercial would work fine for me, but these APIs usually do not have pricing on their websites, which means that the prices are generally very high. In my case out of reach as they cost more than the total income expected for the apps due to them not being general purpose apps for everyone in the world, but specialized apps that are used by few hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

I have been making some progress getting those features out of OpenCV. It might be the easiest route to achieving this on iOS.

If anyone got tips or tricks, they would be greatly appreciated.